# What is the typical number of calls to the comparison function using KNeighborsClassifier in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, knn, nearest-neighbor

friends.

My dataset is the Amazon Employee Access dataset from Kaggle:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/amazon-employee-access-challenge

I am trying to fit a very simple KNN classifier for this dataset:

```
data = pd.read_csv('amazon.csv')
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.iloc[:, 1:], data.iloc[:, 0],
                                                test_size=0.3, random_state=241)
runs = 0
def distOne( x1, x2 ):
    global runs
    runs = runs+1
    if (runs%100000)==0:
        print(runs)
    distance=0
    a=(x1!=x2)
    b = sum(a)
    return b
cl1=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10, \
                     algorithm='ball_tree',\
                     metric=distOne)
cl1.fit( X_train, y_train)

cl1.predict_proba( X_test.iloc[1::2] )
```

The dataset is ~37k lines long.
The fitting step has ~300000 comparison function calls, which, I guess, is reasonable to build a search tree: 37000*10, where 10 is the number of neighbors.

But the prediction step is way harder: I actually never managed to wait till it ended, calling the comparison function several million times.

As far as I understand, if I had no fitting and no search tree at all, still, 37m calls should be enough to find the desired 10 neighbors. 
What am I missing?

It could have been that I somehow messed up with the search function... spotted errors would be appreciated. What it is intended to do is to count the amount of non-equal features in the vectors.

But even if the function is wrong, shouldn't any possible neighbor search converge in 370000 comparisons?

Thanks in advance.